# Hiding contact form and showing confirmation message

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC page which has a large amount of content and a 'contact us' form. Once submitted, I simply wish to hide the form and show a confirmation message.

What is the best way to approach this? I've found that all tutorials use a separate 'thank you' controller and view, but this seems counter-intuitive as I would of course have to repeat my page content.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *partial view* and `Ajax.BeginForm` instead of `Html.BeginForm`. This might be what you've read when they mentioned another controller and view. Partial views can perfectly be reused in various containing views.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable when the page is submitted and then check that variable when the page posts back.  The first time the user enters the page, the value for `submitted` will be false, so your submission page will always display first. e.g.

```
psuedo:

if (!submitted)
   // Display submission form
else
   // Display thank you form.
```

Answer (score 0):

Dangerous to do that.  Could be that refresh resubmits, it's safer to use PRG - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get.   But, to answer the question, if you stay on the same page, use jquery:

```
$('#myform').submit( function() {
  var form = $(this);
  $.post(
    form.attr('action'),
    form.serialize(),
    success: function( response ) {
      form.hide();
    },
    failure: function( respones ) {
      form.addClass('error');
    }
  );
  return false; 
} );
```